# Removing table lines and table space between cells in css

Tags: css, css-tables

I have this site: http://redditlist.com/dir/1026 and I'm stuck on trying to remove spacing between cells so it will look more like this: http://redditlist.com.

Comment: I looked at both of your pages and there are margin and/or padding problems.  View in FF or IE9 and it's completely different.  So how you want it to look is ambiguous.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
table#myTable{
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Use the [border-collapse](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/border-collapse) CSS property to remove space between cells:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

You see spacing between table cells by default because each cell has its own border, the cells don't share borders. This is called "the separated model", as explained in the [Mozilla Developer CSS Reference](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/border-collapse):

> The *separated* model is the traditional HTML table border model. Adjacent cells each have their own distinct borders. The distance between them given by the `border-spacing` property.

You can "remove" the spacing between the cells by making them share borders with each other, which is known as the "collapsed border model":

> In the *collapsed* border model, adjacent table cells share borders.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw that Jaspero was 2 minutes quicker, I appreciate both answers

Comment: @ulvund are you sure about that? My timestamp is `2011-06-30 17:31:52Z`, [Jaspero's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538729/removing-table-lines-and-table-space-between-cells-in-css/6538780#6538780) is `2011-06-30 17:34:15Z`. It appears that ***I*** was the one who was 2 minutes quicker. Also, I link to documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
table.className td
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

or

```
table.className td
{
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

`table td {
  display: table-cell;
}`