# Space between <td>. Why and how can I remove?

Tags: html, css, styles

I create "normal" table and all TD's have "border: 1px solid #e6e6e6" and "margin: 0". TR and TABLE have too "margin/padding: 0" but I still have space between TDs like here: h

[image]

Why? :)

```
<td></td>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VfSdV/

Comment: Can't say much with so little code. Please post your code or, better yet, create a jsfiddle or codepen that duplicates the issue.

Comment: provide some code. the best would be via jsfiddle.net

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing table lines and table space between cells in css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538729/removing-table-lines-and-table-space-between-cells-in-css)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use cellspacing and cellpadding :

```
 <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

 </table>
```

Comment: This is now deprecated. Don't use this. Use CSS `table { border-collapse: collapse; }` instead.

Comment: @RedDragonWebDesign worked for me though. When did it deprecate?

Comment: @S.Alvi Deprecated doesn't always mean deleted. Just means it's officially discouraged and may be removed soon. Run this in an HTML5 validator to confirm its deprecated status: `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Test</title></head><body><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"></table></body></html>` See also: https://www.google.com/search?q=cellspacing+in+table+html+deprecated

Comment: @RedDragonWebDesign I actually did run the html inside the validator. Its does show cellspacing is deprecated/obsolete. Maybe the OP will consider changing his answer?

Answer (score 77):

Since `cellspacing` and `cellpadding` are no longer supported in HTML5, use the following CSS:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VfSdV/3/)

Answer (score 13):

After much trial and error, I ended up using most of what everyone else mentioned plus some from other sites. This worked for me.

```
table {
border:0px;
border-collapse:collapse;
border-spacing:0px;
}

td,img { 
padding:0px; 
border-width:0px; 
margin:0px; 
}
```

Comment: Perfect! In my case, I wanted a table where the tds *did* have borders, they were just *shared* borders. border-collapse + border-spacing was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 5):

Could you try this ?

```
table#table {
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

This piece of css works for me.
Hope it helps :).

Answer (score 0):

This will work for sure.

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Cell spacing** & **Cell padding** depreciated instead use `border-spacing: 0;`

Answer (score -2):

Try this answer too

```
table.tableclassname td
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Well, it _will_ remove the gap between the cells, but it will also radically alter how the cells behave and are rendered.