# Cell spacing in table header

Tags: html, css

i would like to remove white spacing between cells as shown below and also the Total is not really center to the table. How to i center align so that i would be in line with other fields

[image]

please see the code used.

```
<p><br>
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 300px; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-top: solid windowtext 1.0pt;  background: #D9D9D9; text-align: center;">
            <p><span style="font-family: 'Arial',sans-serif; font-weight: normal;">Hardware</span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 200px; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-top: solid windowtext 1.0pt;  background: #D9D9D9; text-align: center;">
           <p><span style="font-family: 'Arial',sans-serif; font-weight: normal;">QTY</span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 200px;  border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-top: solid windowtext 1.0pt;  background: #D9D9D9; text-align: center;">
           <p><span style="font-family: 'Arial',sans-serif; font-weight: normal;">Price</span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 200px;  border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-top: solid windowtext 1.0pt;  background: #D9D9D9; text-align: center;">
           <p><span style="font-family:'Arial',sans-serif; font-weight: normal;">Total</span></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
<br>

    <tr>
        <td style="width: 300px; border-left: solid windowtext 1.0pt;  text-align: center;border-top: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right: none;">
            <p><span style="font-family: 'Arial',sans-serif; font-weight: normal;">Engineering Desktop</span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 200px;  text-align: center;border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right: none;">
           <p><span style="font-family: 'Arial',sans-serif; font-weight: normal;">3</span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 200px;  text-align: center;border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right: none;">
           <p><span style="font-family: 'Arial',sans-serif; font-weight: normal;">503.00 </span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 200px; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; text-align: center;border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right: solid windowtext 1.0pt; ">
           <p><span style="font-family:'Arial',sans-serif; font-weight: normal;">1509</span></p>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style="width: 300px; border-left: solid windowtext 1.0pt;  text-align: center;border-top: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right: none;">
            <p><span style="font-family: 'Arial',sans-serif; font-weight: normal;">BIM-Spec Desktop</span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 200px;  text-align: center;border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right: none;">
           <p><span style="font-family: 'Arial',sans-serif; font-weight: normal;">1</span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 200px;  text-align: center;border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right: none;">
           <p><span style="font-family: 'Arial',sans-serif; font-weight: normal;">765.00 </span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 200px; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; text-align: center;border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right: solid windowtext 1.0pt; ">
           <p><span style="font-family:'Arial',sans-serif; font-weight: normal;">765</span></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table></p>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing table lines and table space between cells in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538729/removing-table-lines-and-table-space-between-cells-in-css)

Comment: You need `border-collapse:collapse` for to remove the space between the cells. The rest is because your HTML is invalid. Fix the broken tags and missing `"` quotes, and that will fix the problem. Also, you should use CSS classes rather than inline-CSS - that meas you're not duplicating the same CSS no lots or elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add **[`border-collapse:collapse;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse)** property  to table

Result:

[image]

```css
table{
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

```html
<p><br>
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 300px; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-top: solid windowtext 1.0pt;  background: #D9D9D9; text-align: center;">
            <p><span style="font-family: 'Arial',sans-serif; font-weight: normal;">Hardware</span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 200px; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-top: solid windowtext 1.0pt;  background: #D9D9D9; text-align: center;">
           <p><span style="font-family: 'Arial',sans-serif; font-weight: normal;">QTY</span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 200px;  border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-top: solid windowtext 1.0pt;  background: #D9D9D9; text-align: center;">
           <p><span style="font-family: 'Arial',sans-serif; font-weight: normal;">Price</span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 200px;  border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-top: solid windowtext 1.0pt;  background: #D9D9D9; text-align: center;">
           <p><span style="font-family:'Arial',sans-serif; font-weight: normal;">Total</span></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
<br>

    <tr>
        <td style="width: 300px; border-left: solid windowtext 1.0pt;  text-align: center;border-top: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right: none;">
            <p><span style="font-family: 'Arial',sans-serif; font-weight: normal;">Engineering Desktop</span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 200px;  text-align: center;border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right: none;">
           <p><span style="font-family: 'Arial',sans-serif; font-weight: normal;">3</span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 200px;  text-align: center;border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right: none;">
           <p><span style="font-family: 'Arial',sans-serif; font-weight: normal;">503.00 </span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 200px; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; text-align: center;border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right: solid windowtext 1.0pt; ">
           <p><span style="font-family:'Arial',sans-serif; font-weight: normal;">1509</span></p>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style="width: 300px; border-left: solid windowtext 1.0pt;  text-align: center;border-top: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right: none;">
            <p><span style="font-family: 'Arial',sans-serif; font-weight: normal;">BIM-Spec Desktop</span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 200px;  text-align: center;border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right: none;">
           <p><span style="font-family: 'Arial',sans-serif; font-weight: normal;">1</span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 200px;  text-align: center;border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right: none;">
           <p><span style="font-family: 'Arial',sans-serif; font-weight: normal;">765.00 </span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 200px; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; text-align: center;border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right: solid windowtext 1.0pt; ">
           <p><span style="font-family:'Arial',sans-serif; font-weight: normal;">765</span></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table></p>
```

Comment: Its still the same Rayes, I have added the whole table tags in the question and updated the tags as advised

Comment: Now check are you want like this?